# Do you have examples when diamond inheritance is useful?

Tags: c++

I am interested in finding examples when diamond inheritance is a good thing. I only read about in theory and haven't run across it in practice.

Comment: Is a "good thing" is somewhat subjective, but is actually *used* in-practice happens closer to home than you may expect : [C++ io streams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io). You likely used it without ever knowing it was even there.

Comment: The diamond of the std::iostream library might be an example

Comment: In interface-based programming, it sometimes happens that your public "interface" class descends from some abstract base and your private impl class descends from both that public class and some concrete implementation of the same abstract base.

Comment: Another example might be a pipeline: Producer -> Consumer/Producer -> ... -> Consumer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best example of diamond inheritance is std::iostream library. This kind of design needs a thorough testing. In general we should avoid this type of structure as much possible so as to reduce maintainance problems later.

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes pops up in interface-based programming, though you can avoid it if you're careful. This is probably best illustrated with an example; otherwise the description would just turn into word salad:

```
// Foo.h

struct IFoo
{
   virtual ~IFoo() {}
   virtual int Bar() = 0;
   virtual int Baz() = 0;
};


// FooBase.h

#include "Foo.h"

class FooBase : public IFoo
{
public:
   int Bar() override { return 0; } // default implementation
   int Baz() override { return 0; } // default implementation
};


// ConcreteFoo.h

#include "Foo.h"

class ConcreteFoo : public IFoo
{
public:
   static ConcreteFoo* Create();
   virtual void SayHello() = 0;
};


// ConcreteFoo.cpp

#include "ConcreteFoo.h"
#include <iostream>

class ConcreteFooImpl : public ConcreteFoo, public FooBase
// Diamond! Both ConcreteFoo and FooBase descend from IFoo.
{
public:
   int Bar() override { return 1; }

   // use default Baz() from FooBase

   void SayHello() override { std::cout << "Hello!"; }
};

ConcreteFoo* ConcreteFoo::Create()
{
   return new ConcreteFooImpl();
}
```

When you're writing new code, you can generally avoid creating this sort of arrangement in the first place. But if you're refactoring to break dependencies in legacy code, you sometimes end up with something that resembles the above as a stop along the way (or maybe the final stop, depending on how much it bothers you :) ).